# Any way to have a loop to build a variable array in ternsorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

New with Tensorflow. If i want do some thing like

```
x_pl=tf.placeholder([None,n])
y_pl=tf.placeholder([None,m])
b_0=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n))
k=tf.Variable)[n,n])
b_1=tf.matmul(b_0,k)
b_2=tf.matmul(b_1,k)
...
b_m=tf.matmul(b_(m-1),k)
y_prd=tf.matmul(x_pl,[b_0,...b_m])
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_prd-y_pl)
```

What's the best way to do this?
it seems to me that i need to have a loop that can generate a variable array before session init all the variables.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry what's the goal exactly? What do you want to do with the variable array?

Comment: only b_0 and K are variable to be fitted, but i need to for a nxm array of bs with b_i = k*b_(i-1). Once i have [b_i], my prediction is calculated as x*[b_i]. from there i get loss and run optimization...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular python loop:

```py
x_pl = tf.placeholder([None, n])
y_pl = tf.placeholder([None, m])
b_0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n))
k = tf.Variable([n,n])

b_list = [b_0]
for i in xrange(1, m + 1):
    b_list.append(tf.matmul(b_list[i-1], k)

y_prd = tf.matmul(x_pl, b_list)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_prd - y_pl)
```